# Change options dynamically with vue js multi select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/26mf8uct/7/) modified wrapper to handle a multiple select for vue js. I'm trying to change value of this inside vue component. Here is my code.

```
<select2-multiple :options="car_options" v-model="input.classification">
       <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
</select2-multiple>
```

And this is my vue script,

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    data: {
        input: {
            classification: []
        },
    },
    created: function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.car_options = [
            {id: "Bubble car", text: 'Bubble car'},
            {id: "diesel", text: 'Diesel'},
            {id: "electric", text: 'Electric'},
            {id: "electric_diesel", text: 'Electric/Diesel'},
            {id: "electric_gasoline", text: 'Electric/Gasoline'},
            {id: "ethanol", text: 'Ethanol'},
            {id: "gasoline", text: 'Gasoline'},
            {id: "hydrogene", text: 'Hydrogene'},
            {id: "lpg", text: 'Liquified petroleum gas (LPG)'},
            {id: "other", text: 'Other'},
        ];
        vm.input.classification = ["Bubble car"];
    }
});
```

What I want's to do is when multi select appears **Bubble car should be automatically selected**. It would be great if someone can help. Multi select is working properly and values also are appearing. **So I think the issue is in here**,

```
vm.input.classification = ["Bubble car"];
```

No error message displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working fine for me - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51sd6e2y/)

```
vm.input.classification = [vm.car_options[0].id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just adding the **selected id** in the `data{}` object like that:

`selected: ["Bubble car"]`

Here is your solution : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omuralcin/gq0j397d/1/)